# Handle observable errors with async pipe in a reactive way

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to implement direct observable streams to my template using async pipe, and handling errors as described in [this S.O answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37358112/2354162)
Code is as follow :

```
export class MyClass {
  private myData$: Observable<any>;
  private hasError$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private shared: SharedService) {
    this.myData$ = this.shared.data$;
    this.hasError$ = this.myData$.catch(err => Observable.of(true)).startWith(false);
  }

}

templateUrl: `
<div *ngFor="let elm of (myData$ | async)?.data">
...
</div>    
<div *ngIf="(hasError$ | async)" class="myDataErrorPlaceholder">
    <h3>Oooops ! An error occured.</h3>
</div>

`
```

No matter what I try, myDataErrorPlaceholder never gets hidden.

I've subscribed to my hasError$ observable for debug, and could see that the initial value from my startWith got broadcasted, but was immediately replaced by the data received by myData$. I can't really wrap my head around this. What causes such behaviour ? How can I implement direct error handling without having to subscribe manually to the Observable in my component ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myData$` will still emit its values in spite of having `.catch` or `.startWith`. I think that the simplest solution for you would be to use `.mapTo(false)` instead to map all emissions to `false`. If there is an error, it will still emit `true` (and complete).

```
this.hasError$ = this.myData$.pipe(catchError(err => of(true)), mapTo(false));
```